# Asp.net Repeater hide image controls if url img null into db and show video controls And vice versa

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have an article repeater and the content should be either image or video. If image url is null, hide image controls and show video controls. If video url is null hide video control and show image control.

**Webform**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrInfo" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>' />
            <video controls height="200" width="385" id="v<%#Eval("Info_Id") %>">
                <source src="<%#Eval("VideoUrl") %>" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

What I do into C# page ??

Comment: <asp:Image  runat ="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>'  />

Answer (score 2):

Solution is creating divs with run at server attribute. Here I'm assuming the values come from database as you mentioned in the title. If that's not the case then try `null` instead of `DBNull.Value`.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrInfo" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div runat="server" visible='<%# Eval("VideoUrl") != DBNull.Value %>'>
            <video controls height="200" width="385" id="v<%#Eval("Info_Id") %>">
                <source src="<%#Eval("VideoUrl") %>" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
        <div runat="server" visible='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") != DBNull.Value %>'>
            <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>' />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved either using code behind method or using Repeater inline code method.

1. Using code behind method

   ```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrInfo" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rptrInfo_ItemDataBound">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Image ID="imgImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>' />
           <asp:Panel id="pnlVideo" runat="server">
           <video controls height="200" width="385" id="v<%#Eval("Info_Id") %>">
               <source src="<%#Eval("VideoUrl") %>" type="video/mp4" />
           </video>
           </asp:Panel>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
   ```

   ```
   protected void rptrInfo_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
       {
           if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
           {
               Image img = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgImage");
               Panel pnlVdo = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlVideo");

               if(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ImageURL") != null)
               {
                  img.Visible = true;
                  pnlVdo.Visible = false;
               }
               else
               {
                  img.Visible = false;
                  pnlVdo.Visible = true;
               }
           }

       }
   ```
2. Using Repeater inline code method

   ```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrInfo" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Image runat="server" Visible='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") != null %>' ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>' />
       <div id="dVideo" runat="server" Visible='<%#Eval("VideoUrl") != null %>'>
           <video controls height="200" width="385" id="<%#Eval("Info_Id") %>">
               <source src='<%#Eval("VideoUrl") %>' type="video/mp4" />
           </video>
       </div>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
   ```